# Some of the icons from Devicons not rendering properly

Tags: plugin-devicons

I installed the following plugins in NeoVim after installing the Nerd Fonts.

```
Plug 'tiagofumo/vim-nerdtree-syntax-highlight'
Plug 'ryanoasis/vim-devicons'
```

And this is how NerdTree in Vim looks,

[image]

As you can see the glyph icons for CSS3 and HTML5 are not the one's we see with modern editors, however the icons for python and javascript are rendered just fine.

So is the expected behavior or I am missing something. I tested this both with `SourceCodePro` and `FiraCode` and I got the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize any icon by adding the following line to your `.vimrc`

`let g:WebDevIconsUnicodeDecorateFileNodesExtensionSymbols['css']  = ''`

Simply change the 'css' and '' to what you would like (the CSS symbol is U+F13C).

A good website to look for icons is [nerdfonts.com](https://nerdfonts.com/#cheat-sheet).

While in Vim, the plugin [vim-characterize](https://github.com/tpope/vim-characterize) by the great *tpope* is ideal to identify up any character you come across.

Comment: Can you tell me how did you get this unicode string for CSS icon, so that I can find for some other file type icons as well ?

Comment: Expanded my answer above.

Comment: I went through nerdfonts.com earlier as well but could not get a way to get the unicode character of the same.

Comment: Once you look up the icon, the text in the dotted box is the hex value. To enter it in vim use `ctrl-v` then `u` followed by the four-digit hex (in this case `f13c`) You can also paste that value into a [unicode converter](http://www.endmemo.com/unicode/unicodeconverter.php) and copy the result.